# Exclude Filtered data from Group Totals in Report Builder

Tags: filtering, ssrs-grouping

I have a stored procedure pulling data based on a parameter based "list date" range and rolling it up by month.   My output gives me rows based on the month. I need to filter out the "Previous" values which actually represent 'To Date'

Month-------# Listed--------$ Listed

Previous---------125--------1,000.00

January-----------25-----------100.00

February----------50-----------500.00

To Date----------200---------1,600.00

I can easily use a Group filter or even a Tablix filter to eliminate the detail row for the 'Previous' entries.

Month-------# Listed--------$ Listed

January-----------25-----------100.00

February----------50-----------500.00

To Date----------200---------1,600.00

However, I cannot find a way to exclude the filtered detail from the Group totals.    What I need to see is:

Month-------# Listed--------$ Listed

January-----------25-----------100.00

February----------50-----------500.00

To Date-----------75-----------600.00

I don't have the option of modifying the stored procedure.  Any thoughts on how I can do this in Report Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Using Tablix filtering and filtering out Previous should do the trick.